# Does there exist an infinite path of one colored sub-tiles?

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, puzzle, coloring, tiling

This question came to my mind when I was contemplating on the tilling of bathroom's floor:

> What is the maximum number of colors we can use for an optimum coloring of $N^2$ square sub-tiles of $N×N$ square
> block tile, which for every
> tiling of whole plane with these identical tile blocks(only four states of
> rotating $90$ degree blocks can be used) there exist a two-head
> infinite path for at least one color of the sub-tiles?

[image: 6×6 square block tiles coloured with 3 colors]

[image: two path of different sub-tiles colors]
**Note:** A two-head infinite path of one coloured sub-tiles consist of elements of sub-tiles with the same color which for each element in the path there exist two another non-adjacent elements of the path from its 8 adjacent sub-tiles squares.(also it does not intersect with itself for example does not make circle)

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. What is an "optimum colouring"? Are the tiles randomly coloured? Are all the tiles the same? Can we choose the particular way to colour the tile?

Comment: @JaapScherphuis you'r right , it seems a bit complicates the way I presented my question. The objective here is finding two simultaneous related settings in order to satisfy demandings. First: finding the maximum number of colors say$k$,second: find the best coloring of $N^2$ squares with the $k$ colors which guarantees existence of at least 1 two-head infinite path for every tiling of infinite plane. The blocks are identical ,I added just right now. thanks for mention

Comment: For more applicable version of this question see the overflow version: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/380438/maximum-number-of-colors-for-an-optimal-tiling-which-guaranties-infinite-paths

Comment: If you have a tile where the middle squares of all four of the sides are connected by one colour, then the tile will obviously always generate infinite paths. You can connect them with $2N-1$ squares, allowing the other $N^2-2N+1$ squares to be different colours, for a total of $N^2-2N+2$ colours.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis what about for even $N$ ? Does the formula gives maximum value  for odd $N$? Also it seems for some tiling your solution gives close paths!

Comment: For even N it does not matter which of the middle squares on each side you use since you allow diagonal connections. You can connect them more efficiently with three diagonal lines, which makes $N+\lfloor\frac{N-1}2\rfloor$ squares of one colour. I think this is the best possible. If you connect only 3 sides, there will be tilings possible without infinite paths, though a randomly chosen infinite tiling will [almost surely](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) have such paths.